# Prevent C# service from creating user profile

Tags: c#

I have created a windows service that runs powershell scripts on remote systems using WINRM.

The issue is that when it connects to the remote machine it is creating a user profile as if the user is interactively logging in. It creates a new profile in the registry list and creates user profile folders, Documents, Desktop etc...

How can I prevent this profile from being created?

Here is my code:

```
 WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo()
   {
      ComputerName = this.HostName
   };

 using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo))
    {
    using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create(RunspaceMode.NewRunspace))
    {
        ps.Runspace = runspace;

        var cmdText = File.ReadAllText($"{pathToScripts}\\{script.name}.ps1");

            if (ps.Runspace.RunspaceStateInfo.State != RunspaceState.Broken)
            {
                ps.AddScript(cmdText);
                PSDataCollection<PSObject> outputCollection =
                    new PowerShellHelper(ps, this.Logger, this.HostName)
                        .ExecuteAsynchronously(new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0));
                var dt = ConvertToDataTable(outputCollection, script.name);
                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    new DataBaseUpdater(this.Logger, this.Zone, this.ConString,
                        this.HostName).Update(script.name, dt);
                }
            }
            else
            {

                this.Logger.Error(
                    $"[{System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()}]:[{this.HostName}]: Runspace State:{runspace.RunspaceStateInfo.State.ToString()}");
            }

        else
        {
            this.Logger.Error(
                $"Output for {script.name} does not contain rec_num field. Ensure that your powershell script is outputing this field.");
            break;
            //statement.Break();
        }
        if (ps.Runspace.RunspaceStateInfo.State != RunspaceState.Closed)
        {
            ps.Runspace.CloseAsync();
            ps.Runspace.Close();
            ps.Runspace.Dispose();
     }
 }}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the [`NoMachineProfile` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.runspaces.wsmanconnectioninfo.nomachineprofile?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0#System_Management_Automation_Runspaces_WSManConnectionInfo_NoMachineProfile) on the `connectionInfo` object before creating the runspace:

```
connectionInfo.NoMachineProfile = true;
```

Comment: Let me try that!